# Ho to sign Symbian 60 v3 Edition file

Tags: symbian3

I need to sign a symbian series v3 application which may be installed on any phone without signing again and again. Can some body help me in signing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as there are no developer certificates available, nor are there real symbian signing, you have only the option on using self-signing. Check [nokia developer wiki for Self-signing help](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_guide_for_creating/signing_sis_files)

Comment: I tried to create a key and signing cert, but CMD says that its not a valid command. Anyother way to create a key and cert?

Comment: basically, its some kind of mistake you have made, thus check the tool help, and other possible docs on how it can be used.